# How to refresh Bearer token with each call of `CreateClient` (possibly by overriding `CreateClient`)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make use of `IHttpClientFactory` for the first time in a .NET Core 3.1 MVC project. I am using `HttpClient` to make calls to the Microsoft Graph API.

Whenever I need to make a call to the API I need to first check that the authentication token the application has is valid (i.e. hasn't expired) and, if not, use the refresh token to obtain a new authentication token.

Before learning of `IHttpClientFactory` I was initialising an instance of `HttpClient` for my application
and then whenever I needed to make an API call I'd first call my own `PrepareHttpClient()` function, so it'd go like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private readonly IOAuthService _oAuthService;

    public MyController(IOAuthService oAuthService)
    {
        _oAuthService = oAuthService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var url = "http://whatever";
        await PrepareHttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        // Other stuff
    }

    private async Task PrepareHttpClient()
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        string bearerToken = await _oAuthService.GetOAuthBearerToken();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {bearerToken}");
    }
}
```

The `GetOAuthBearerToken` function is in a service which, as you can see, is injected into the controller and it basically does the dance of checking if the current token is expired and obtaining a new one if required, and it returns the valid token as a string. I don't think the full code of that function is necessary here but I can add it if required.

After learning about `IHttpClientFactory` and the fact that you can give an `HttpClient` a name and configure it in `Startup.cs` I thought "Great, I'll just call the `GetOAuthBearerToken` function when configuring the client". Something like

```
services.AddHttpClient("OneDrive", async(c) => {
    string bearerToken = await IOAuthService.GetOAuthBearerToken();
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {bearerToken}");
});
```

However, there are a number of problems with this:

1. Injecting a service in to the `Startup` class seems to be a no-go, which makes sense, so I can't inject my `IOAuthService` as I do in the controller.
2. The `GetOAuthBearerToken` itself uses `HttpClient` to obtain updated API tokens, and using DI to inject an `IHttpClientFactory` into a function which is itself injected into `Startup` sounds like... I'm losing my mind.

Ultimately I realised that none of that mattered because I need to check and refresh the API token every time I make a call, not just when the client is instantiated when the application starts. So it seems to me that the most elegant solution would be to override the `CreateClient` method in `IHttpClientFactory`, which I call right before making every API call, so that it could call my `GetOAuthBearerToken` function and then I'd know that every time I called `CreateClient` the `HttpClient` was good to go, with a valid bearer token in the header.

My question is (finally!), how would I go about overriding `CreateClient` in this way? Assuming that's the best way to achieve my aim.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if someone could make this a comment.

The first thing I notice is you forget to clear the headers and add the new header for each request, for the instance you are registering in your startup.

**Edit**:
I'll just go ahead and answer it. Sorry I don't have any sort of c# compiler or intellisense.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private static IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = new IHttpClientFactory();
    private readonly IOAuthService _oAuthService;

    public MyController(IOAuthService oAuthService,IHttpClientFactory myfactory)
    {
        _oAuthService = oAuthService;
        httpClientFactory = myfactory;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var url = "http://whatever";
        HttpClient myclient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyNamedClient");
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
        // Other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest for production code, to check the expiration time on the token every time, and only making the request when it is ~ 30 seconds left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris. My question probably isn't as clear as it could be since I wrote it at 2am, but my issue isn't how to call the named `HttpClient` in my controller, it's how to essentially do the work currently being performed by the `PrepareHttpClient` function automatically as part of the `CreateClient` call. As you can see, `PrepareHttpClient` DOES clear the `HttpClient` headers and add the new one every time, but you're right, my example of the desired code in `Startup` doesn't. I didn't spend long on that bit since I knew it wasn't a viable solution anyway.